# I want my application's user to play every video with MyVideoPLayer

Tags: java, android, file-permissions

I had developed a video player which is working fine. Now i want from user to play every song with it. I mean whenever user clicks a video file, it should play with `my video player` or how can I add **my video player** to the alert dialog which appears when a video file is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following intent-filters to your video player activity:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="rtsp" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/sdp" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

This will add your app to the list of apps that can play Videos and RTSP streams from the internet (remove the first filter if you don't want to support streaming).

Comment: Thanks Raghav. It works but there is an other problem.... i used path to play a specific video file in my my video player... when we click in list of apps that can play Videos it throughs a nullpointerexceptoin .... how we can get  path on that click to play the file????????